# How to disconnect from OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm connecting using VPNBook servers and it works fine with this command:

```
 sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/vpnbook-udp-53.ovpn --auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/password.txt
```

but I just can't seem to figure out how to stop it without a reboot.

I've tried `service openvpn stop` and `/etc/init.d/vpnbook stop`, but that doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: How exactly with ifconfig?

Comment: Which one would it be?
eth0,
lo,
tun2, or wlan0

Comment: simply do >  sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart <

Comment: I am curious, when a VPN is started this way does it not show up in the network manager.  I have only always used the network manager connect and disconnect and don't currently have a VPN to test but wondered.

Answer (score 83):

This command definitely works for me, and it should work for you too.

```
sudo killall openvpn
```

Comment: Might require `sudo apt-get install psmisc` on some builds

Comment: I had to kill -9 it on Ubuntu 16.04 (yes I know...)

Comment: this just kills every openvpn process. I have several and want to close just some. Is there a better way?

Comment: @johannes_lalala, you probably already figured this out, but this worked on my side: `openvpn3 session-manage --config "$CONFIGURATION_PROFILE_NAME" --disconnect` Hopefully that will help someone out. BTW, I got the command from this wiki page: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux

Comment: @SpencerD I tried it and got `If 'openvpn3' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf openvpn3`. I also tried `openvpn session-manage --config "$CONFIGURATION_PROFILE_NAME" --disconnect` (without the 3) instead, but the parameters seem not fitting:
`Options error: I'm trying to parse "session-manage" as an --option parameter but I don't see a leading '--'
Use --help for more information.
`

Comment: @johannes_lalala You can use `ps` or `lsof -i` to find all processes and `grep` it for `openvn` [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/558797/830570). After you have the Process-ID, you can use `kill -9 <yourPIDhere>` to kill just one process.

Comment: @Cadoiz, it sounds like you have a different version of OpenVPN installed than the version I referenced in my comment.

Answer (score 46):

I had same problem with disconnecting from openvpn3

I end up creating [this small repo](https://github.com/shmalex/openvpn3_manager) that helps manage the openvpn3 sessions

To disconnect the session, you have know the session's Path

```
openvpn3 session-manage --session-path $OPENVPN3_SESSION_PATH --disconnect
```

the session path could be found via

```
openvpn3 sessions-list

> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         Path: /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/7a42f37asc8d9s424c8b534sd331d6dd56e8
>      Created: Tue Dec  8 10:44:57 2020                  PID: 9495
>        Owner: shmalex                                Device: tun0
>  Config name: client.ovpn  (Config not available)
> Session name: ***.***.***.***
>       Status: Connection, Client connected
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
OPENVPN3_SESSION_PATH=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/7a42f37asc8d9s424c8b534sd331d6dd56e8
openvpn3 session-manage --session-path $OPENVPN3_SESSION_PATH --disconnect
```

You can use [my repo](https://github.com/shmalex/openvpn3_manager) to perform same actions with help of bash files.

Comment: This is THE CORRECT answer, and should be the accepted one too. I get, however, why the answers with kill command are so upvoted, I wouldn't blame them or the voters, I wish the disconnect command was really practically 'a' command.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer, and thanks for writing those bash files - makes life much easier!

Answer (score 21):

The successful steps in my case were:

```
# stop the service    
$ sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn stop

# find the process if it is still running for some reason
$ lsof -i | grep openvpn

# kill the proccess(s) by its PID
$ kill -9 <PID>

# if necessary restart the service again
$ sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start
```

For some reason `killall -SIGINT openvpn` did not work for me, but the steps above did.

Comment: Well, this is the best answer in my opinion. Killing process is the weird method, but requesting the service to stop should do things as it must.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't "kill -9" things until you've tried an interrupt or otherwise cleanly existing it first.  Programs can catch an interrupt and do cleanup, but can't catch signal nine (term).  Particularly in the case of openvpn, killing it with `-9` does not allow the post scripts to run, and very likely will leave now-invalid routes laying around.  Ideally, you'd `kill -SIGINT`, then wait a few seconds for the pid to end, and only go with `-SIGTERM` / `-9` if it didn't exit before that.

Comment: Just for reference: "9" ist SIGKILL and "15" is SIGTERM - see `kill -L`

Comment: how do I selectively close certain vpn connections?

Comment: not tested, but you can use `kill -9 $(pidof <processname>)`

Answer (score 13):

I stumbled upon having 2 open sessions with the same config path.
So I could not use

`openvpn3 session-manage --disconect --config <config_path>`

> session-manage: ** ERROR ** More than one session with the given configuration profile name was found.

So I made a script to loop through sessions (session ids are not always the same as the config paths)

```sh
ACTIVE_SESSIONS=$(openvpn3 sessions-list | grep -i 'path' | awk '{p=index($0, ":");print $2}')
echo $ACTIVE_SESSIONS
for instance in $ACTIVE_SESSIONS; do
    openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --session-path ${instance}
done
```

Comment: Well, this is nice! 
I've integrated the first command as External tool into phpstorm. Btw I would have used the script if I had more active sessions! I'll keep it, just in case .. Nice work! :-)

Answer (score 10):

In case `sudo killall openvpn` does not finish the job (I experienced it a few times) then a sharp and fatal solution would be:

```
pgrep openvpn | xargs sudo kill -9
```

Comment: `sudo pkill openvpn` whould do the job as well.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
killall -SIGINT openvpn
```

You can get more info on [the different signals you can send here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#control).

Comment: `killall -SIGINT openvpn`
openvpn(15360): Operation not permitted
openvpn: no process found

`sudo killall -SICINT openvpn` 
SICINT: unknown signal; killall -l lists signals.

Comment: `sudo killall openvpn` in a new terminal worked for me.

Comment: @Adam: it's `SIGINT`, not `SICINT`

Comment: The kill and killall commands send SIGTERM by default, which the documentation says has the same effect as SIGINT.  So, either would work equivalently - if spelled properly. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal you just started OpenVPN.

Comment: What if it was started w/the -daemon (background) flag? It's not possible in this case.

Comment: Also this leaves 'tun0' as an interface, so it's not possible to restart without rebooting or doing some system config file editing while running.

Comment: What if teh terminal was closed accidentally. ?

Comment: @Dennis `ifconfig tun0 down` helps in this case.

Answer (score 6):

`sudo openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --config $'client'.ovpn`

Replace client with the corresponding name.
This will shutdown the session.

Answer (score 5):

after running `sudo killall openvpn` or `service openvpn stop` the virtual interface "tun0" would remain opened and referenced in route table, so actually related connections would be lost since openvpn service is killed.

the solution is to delete this virtual connection after killing openvpn service, as it is created everytime  when openvpn service gets connected.

so you need to run below commands for disconnecting openvpn:

```
$ sudo killall openvpn
$ sudo ip link delete tun0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my one-liner that easily gets the session-path using `grep` and `cut`:

```
openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --session-path $(openvpn3 sessions-list | grep Path | cut -b 15-)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command, where `0` is the tunnel number:

```
sudo ifconfig tun0 down
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command:

```
   $openvpn3 session-manage --session-path /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/..... --disconnect
```

you may get the path using command below:

```
openvpn3 sessions-list
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

When you login to ovpn. It will give a session file with full path. Put that full path after --session-path in below command

```
openvpn3 session-manage --session-path /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/<session file> --disconnect
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-rc.d openvpn disable
```

Or edit the config file in `/etc/default/openvpn` with

```
sudo nano /etc/default/openvpn
```

And uncomment the line:

```
#AUTOSTART="none"
```

So it looks like:

```
AUTOSTART="none"
```

Then you'll have to run:

- `sudo service openvpn start <vpn-name>`
  to manually start the VPN.
- `sudo service openvpn stop <vpn-name>`
  to manually stop the VPN.

Where `<vpn-name>` is the config file name
located in `/etc/openvpn` without the `.conf` extension
and without the `< >`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to disconnect all vpn sessions or a specific vpn session

`vpnd.sh [session path]`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

session=$1

if [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    echo "Usage : ./vpnd.sh [session path]"
    echo "E.g. disconnect specific session"
    echo "vpnd.sh /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/b7a35c15s95ffs4cd9sa867sc473a37d77a0"
    echo "E.g. disconnect all sessions"
    echo "vpnd.sh"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -z "$session" ]; then
    openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --session-path "${session}"
    exit 0
fi

readarray -t vpn_sessions < <(openvpn3 sessions-list | sed -nE 's/^\s*Path:\s+(\S*)$/\1/p')
   
for session in ${vpn_sessions[@]} ; do  
    if [ ! -z "${session}" ]; then
        echo "Closing session ${session}..."
        openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --session-path "${session}"
    fi
done

openvpn3 session-manage --cleanup
openvpn3 sessions-list
```

Note that you can get a list of active session paths via

`openvpn3 sessions-list`

Answer (score 1):

Quick one-liner:

```bsh
sudo openvpn3 sessions-list | grep -ioP '/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/\w+' | xargs -I{} sudo openvpn3 session-manage --path {} --disconnect
```

Answer (score 1):

`openvpn3 sessions-list`

It will print a PID number

`sudo kill -9 {PID}`  without the curly braces of course.

Answer (score 1):

For me works this:

```
your@prompt: openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --path </PATH/PROVIDED/IN/SESSION/START>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just send SIGINT signal to openvpn and it will stop gracefully.

https://openvpn.net/community-resources/controlling-a-running-openvpn-process/

> Running on Linux/BSD/Unix
>
> OpenVPN accepts several signals:
>
> ```
> SIGUSR1 -- Conditional restart, designed to restart without root privileges
> SIGHUP -- Hard restart
> SIGUSR2 -- Output connection statistics to log file or syslog
> SIGTERM, SIGINT -- Exit
> ```

Here another info from openvpn manual:

> SIGNALS
> SIGHUP Cause OpenVPN to close all TUN/TAP and network connections, restart, re-read the configuration file (if any), and
> reopen TUN/TAP and network connections.
>
> ```
>    SIGUSR1
>           Like SIGHUP`, except don't re-read configuration file, and possibly don't close and reopen TUN/TAP device, re-read key files,
> ```
>
> preserve local IP address/port, or preserve most recently
> authenticated remote IP address/port based on --persist-tun, --persist-key, --persist-local-ip and --persist-remote-ip options respectively (see above).
>
> ```
>           This signal may also be internally generated by a timeout condition, governed by the --ping-restart option.
>
>           This signal, when combined with --persist-remote-ip, may be sent when the underlying parameters of the host's network interface
> ```
>
> change such as when the host is a DHCP  client  and  is
> assigned a new IP address.  See --ipchange for more information.
>
> ```
>    SIGUSR2
>           Causes OpenVPN to display its current statistics (to the syslog file if --daemon is used, or stdout otherwise).
>
>    SIGINT, SIGTERM
>           Causes OpenVPN to exit gracefully.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

an a comment to the answer from @allgamer  :

for openvpn3,

the command is:

$ sudo killall openvpn3-servic

tested on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Then this is not another answer it is a comment to someone else answer.

Comment: very well pointed out @David , unfortunately i have too little reputation to comment on stackexchange, but enough to post  an answer. if you can paste a comment, i will gladly delete this answer of mine.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

in the terminal,

```
openvpn3 sessions-list
```

Here you can see your active sessions, you can see its Config Name (usually its xxxxx.ovpn)

then you can type :

```
openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --config ${session_config_name}
```

change `${session_config_name}` with your config name that you listed previously. Then you'll get disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

```
openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --interface tun0
```

(where `tun0` is the name of the VPN tunnel you see in `ip route show`)

---

Explanation:

Just killing it (even politely with sigterm: `sudo pkill openvpn3`) does not fully clean up the routing table (`ip route show`):

```
 default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp58s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.100 metric 600 
+<your employer's IP address> via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp58s0 
 192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp58s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.100 metric 600
```

What does is `--disconnect`.

As for what argument to identify the connection:

- `--config` does not work for me:

  ```
  openvpn3 session-manage --disconnect --config ~/Downloads/Openvpn3\ Profile.ovpn 
  session-manage: ** ERROR ** No sessions started with the configuration profile name was found
  ```
- `--path` changes each time (you could script around that).
- `--interface` is stable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly late here but to improve previous answers, I have added following as an allias

```
alias ovpn-up='sudo openvpn3 session-start --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn.ovpn'
alias ovpn-ls='sudo openvpn3 sessions-list'
alias ovpn-down='sudo openvpn3 session-manage --session-path $(sudo openvpn3 sessions-list | grep Path | cut -d':' -f2) --disconnect'
```

so I can quickly connect/disconnect and list the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

For beginner don't go for a complicated process, just use Task Manager, search for openvpn and terminate it directly from there

[image: given image to see]

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @nat-naydenova's answer, it happened that just a grep on  `openvpn` was not enough as the shell script itself had openvpn in the name.

Also, for some reason, using `kill -9` also killed my virtual internet connection in Debian. Yet, `kill -15` worked just fine.

So here is the proposal:

```
echo "Looking for PID of openvpn..."
#1. looking for /usr/sbin/openvpn to avoid confusion with other files
#2. extracting PID with sed, since we get all the info (as opposed to lsof -i)
#3. removing extra spaces with tr

pid=$(lsof -w | grep /usr/sbin/openvpn | sed -n 's/openvpn\(.*\)root.*/\1/p' | tr -d " ")


echo "Found $pid"
echo "Attempting to kill PID: $pid"

#Uncomment if you think this is really required. I don't think so
##Stopping openvpn service
#service openvpn stop

#Killing softly
kill -15 $pid

#Uncomment if you think this is really required. I don't think so
##Restarting openvpn service
#service openvpn start

echo "Done killing openvpn."
```

Acknowledgements:

- Thanks ChatGPT for the help with the command chaining with grep + sed + tr.
- Thanks to people writing those f***ng `man`uals  ;)